# Extracting words from row entries to columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and python.

**My DataFrame looks like this:**

```
Search query             Impressions         Clicks
iPhone X 2019            10000               50
iPhoneX 2019             15                  64
iPhone 11                60                  87
Nokia 3310               444                 61
Nokia 3310 best phone    1                   30
```

I am trying to create another column named `Word` which would have values for each word in each `Search query` row.

**Example:**

```
Search query             Impressions         Clicks         Word
iPhone X 2019            10000               50             iPhone
iPhone X 2019            10000               50             X
iPhone X 2019            10000               50             2019
iPhoneX 2019             15                  64             iPhoneX
iPhoneX 2019             15                  64             2019
iPhone 11                60                  87             iPhone
iPhone 11                60                  87             11
Nokia 3310               444                 61             Nokia
Nokia 3310               444                 61             3310
Nokia 3310 best phone    1                   30             Nokia
Nokia 3310 best phone    1                   30             3310
Nokia 3310 best phone    1                   30             best
Nokia 3310 best phone    1                   30             phone
```

So each row is multiplied by the number of strings in column `Search query` and column `Word` holds each string in the column `Search query`.

**What I've tried:**

```
def f(x):
    x = x.split(' ')
    y = len(x)
    # at this point I am not sure how I would apply the multiplication and assign each word in 'Word' column once every word
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new column `Word` filled by splitted values and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) them, last convert values to default index:

```
df = df.assign(Word = df['Search query'].str.split()).explode('Word').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
             Search query  Impressions  Clicks     Word
0           iPhone X 2019        10000      50   iPhone
1           iPhone X 2019        10000      50        X
2           iPhone X 2019        10000      50     2019
3            iPhoneX 2019           15      64  iPhoneX
4            iPhoneX 2019           15      64     2019
5               iPhone 11           60      87   iPhone
6               iPhone 11           60      87       11
7              Nokia 3310          444      61    Nokia
8              Nokia 3310          444      61     3310
9   Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30    Nokia
10  Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30     3310
11  Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30     best
12  Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30    phone
```

Comment: Thank you, will look in to `DataFrame.explode`! Why would I need to convert values to default index at the end?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I think because some pandas functions like reindex failed with duplicated index and I think if default index it should be better performance.